# Redirection of stdout to stdin in other languages that BASH when you fork or execute a program

Tags: bash, api, process, programming-languages, io-redirection

I need to code a program which execute several subprograms, using pipes and redirection. So since I need to use some data structures and functions I want to avoid use Bash for that matter. So far, I know how to use redirection in bash without any problem.

```
$ ./myprogram -f 1 -h -l < mysource.dat | myprogram2
```

Some my question are the next:

1. how can you code this line in other language such as C, Python, Perl, Java or Ruby, avoiding system ("....")?
2. Also, I wonder which language provide the best process managements tools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to question 1 in Python:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
f=file("mysource.dat")
p1 = Popen(["./myprogram","-f","1","-h"."-l"], stdin=f, stdout=PIPE)
f.close()
p2 = Popen(["myprogram2"], stdin=p1.stdout)
p1.stdout.close()
p1.wait()
p2.wait()
```

More information at the [subprocess module documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html).

Regarding question 2, Java isn't likely to be the best option. C will allow you to use `pipe`, `fork`, `dup2`, and `exec` system calls to do everything, but involves some more typing. The others are most likely equally good, depending on your personal scripting preferences.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, I definitively will move to python its seems to be much easier :D